# How one should use the reality of realistic space combat as a world foundation?

Tags: hard-science, space-travel, spaceships, space-warfare

many believe that space combat as it'll actually be instead of what you see in star wars is not exciting. with the show, the expanse for example, which made an effort to be true to reality, i heard it was not as popular as star wars and star trek.

But I myself see a huge opportunity. The silence, size and unforgiving nature of space does add a fear factor and sense of foreboding built on the foundation of it being a soundless void with it so big, you never see enemies--with a single mistake being your last. However, I conclude that there's other considerations on how it can be a cornerstone of the gameplay, film, and world space in a book.

similar to the variety of horror games like slenderman.

how would one build on space combat as it really is as the foundation of the story in a way that keeps you on the edge of your seat?

Comment: I am not sure I really understand what you are asking. Moreover, which kind of scientific research/papers do you expect on space combat as world foundation?

Comment: Are you asking how to build an entire world specifically around realistic space combat, as your title asks (maybe space combat or simulations thereof are really popular in your world's culture?) or asking how to represent realistic space combat in an interesting way, as your question's text asks? These seem to be two different questions.

Comment: This got closed because you're asking for an entire syllabus in creative writing, which is well beyond the scope of this site. Also, the reality of space has rarely produced substantial popularity. It was tried back with [*Space: 1999*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space:_1999). People aren't all that interested in reality - what they want is a good story and only as much reality as supports the good story. All the reality in the world won't fix a bad story.

Answer (score 7):

I would compare space warfare to submarine actions.

There is nothing to see in submarine warfare either, and you are surrounded by an unforgiving element in which any hull breach could be deadly. If the hull does get breached, things get interesting for the crew.

The enemy is invisible and you will not know about an attack until it hits. You are dependent on an array of high-tech gizmos and just hoping that it all works, and waiting helplessly to see what happens.

Still, submarine warfare is not that boring in books and movies. :)

Comment: agree mostly but stealth in space is hard

Comment: @jk the visibility is also hard. You're in a pressurised container at high velocities where a tiny breach could mean the end with nearly no opportunities to survive. I think it's a good comparison.

Comment: @jk up to a point. But to the crewmembers on the vessel, the comparison may be apt.

Answer (score 4):

**Like an airplane**

Edit: only now I see a hard science tag, but not sure what is requested in that case.

There are already scenarios where this is happening, both in combat as well as in civilian situations. Airplanes are moving at high speeds in the sky. Although we use our vision, it is actually a poor way to see. Most of it is assisted by computers and their displays. An example:

In a rare crash of 2 planes in the sky it was suggested that the pilots of one plane had to have looked left out of the cockpit to see the oncoming plane. They knew it was heading their way and should've looked to take correct evasive action. After some research though, they (and me in my own study for a course) found that it would have been impractical. The plane would've looked like a tiny dot, which is difficult to ascertain the trajectory from if you can find it. Until the last few seconds, where the plane visually increases size enormously. Unfortunately it is too late to do anything about it then.
Spacecraft are even further apart, making visual ques practically impossible.

Computers now govern everything in the sky. They calculate most if the information and represent it in a simple format back to us. You're flying on instruments, not your sight. In combat planes it's much the same. Incomimg fire, friendlies or radar detection isn't done visually anymore.

In space you can make the horror the same if not worse as you say. You can't see what is happening, you just hear a beeping noise and might feel the thrusters make evasive manoeuvres or hear countermeasures being deployed. Even things counting down, like the machine guns in Alien, can give a deep horror. Give it an extra twist like in the movie Gravity with being outside. You might see a glimpse of something passing by, but most often you would never even see it, as it's so fast. Except rockets, but you'll only see a tiny speck of light until the last moment.

Edit:
Weapons can be "conventional". Rockets are most reliable, but special guns, or even simply leave (camouflaged) space debris on the trajectory of the enemy spacecraft. Finally EMP might be used, depending onnthe environment, but I think most are pretty well shielded as in space everything is turned up not just to 11, but to 111 compared to Earth. Each has their own advantage and disadvantage, each can hold their own form of horror. Computers can track a ton easily in space, but you'll rarely see it...

Comment: " The plane would've looked like a tiny dot, which is difficult to ascertain the trajectory from if you can find it" - you are not quite right. WWII air battles were all based on visual contact. There is a very simple rule: "if this dot is not moving relative to cabin datails - you are on collision (interception) course". And computers does not govern everything in the sky for now.

Comment: WWII planes are no comparison from modern planes. Speed of propellor planes is simply low, while jet powered or better are mind-boggling fast. And yes you can see that the dot is not moving so your trajectory is or was crossing each other, if you're coming from the front or back. Sideways you have to account for your own momentum. Finally, computers are everywhere nowadays. People make decisions still, but few comes from just looking around your cockpit or from an ATC tower.

Comment: "Sideways you have to account for your own momentum" - you are totaly wrong here. Googgle for "proportional guidance". As for speeds - they were almost the same as airtraffic in airport zone now

Comment: I'm ok with being corrected, but proportional guidance has nothing to do with the LoS changes from a cockpit? It is just about adjusting the trajectory? Could you elaborate what I'm missing? Regardless, the point of the whole matter is that it isn't done primarily visually. Speeds are high, visibility through human eyes is not as good as intruments, so you use the information of screens. This counts doubly so for satellites. High speed and small bodies. You don't see the thousands of sattelites on feeds from the more distant sattelites either.